# No such file or directory Compiler Error in Xcode 4.0 on APNs Urban Airship Client Side Integration?

Tags: iphone, ios, compiler-errors, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am trying to integrate Apple Push Notification Service based on Urban Airship,Am trying implements this two links [FirstLink](https://www.urbanairship.com/docs/airship_lib.html) and [SecondLinks](http://www.jc-evans.com/uploads/Urban_Airship_Instructions.txt) .Unfortunately i getting error [image].
No Such File Or Directory , I tried delete and drag again  Airship folder in My project and Quit and Open `Xcode`. How can i over come this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Last i found the mistake please refer [this](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/questions/51394-could-you-possibly-make-the-installation-instructions-more-vague-)